# on trailhead facing issue Error: Faraday::ClientError. Message

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, trailhead

On this trailhead ( https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-lightning-components/quickstart-lightning-components3 ). when i click on the verify button it's throwing error

> Step not yet complete  There was an unhandled exception. Please
>   reference ID: QUHIDFJQ. Error: Faraday::ClientError. Message:
>   MALFORMED_QUERY: When retrieving results with Metadata or FullName
>   fields, the query qualificatio​ns must specify no more than one row
>   for retrieval. Result size: 4

I have follow same steps which is mentioned in this trailhead.

Apex Controller code

```
public class MyContactListController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> getContacts(Id recordId) {
    return [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone From Contact Where AccountId = :recordId];
 }
}
```

Component Code

```
<aura:component controller="MyContactListController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="Account" type="Account" />
<aura:attribute name="Contacts" type="Contact" />
<aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List" />
<force:recordData aura:id="accountRecord"
              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
              targetFields="{!v.Account}"
              layoutType="FULL"
              />
<lightning:card iconName="standard:contact" title="{! 'Contact List for ' + v.Account.Name}">
<!-- Contact list goes here -->
</lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

Component added on United Oil & Gas Corp and Activate and then click Assign as Org Default

[image]

Comment: That's a Tooling API error from inside the validation checker. Do you have multiple Lighting pages with the same display name, perhaps?

Comment: how it can be possible lightning pages with same name

Answer (score 2):

This is a Tooling API error thrown inside Trailhead's validation checker. It looks like Trailhead is attempting to retrieve the metadata for some entity by using the `Metadata` property in its Tooling API query, which requires that exactly one result be returned, but its query is matching multiple metadata entities in your Trailhead org.

Since we don't know exactly what query Trailhead is running, your recourse is going to be

- Contact Trailhead support.
- Start fresh with a new Trailhead playground.
- Review your Trailhead org and see if you might have accidentally created duplicates on any of the metadata that's used in this module. One possibility would be, *if* Trailhead is running a Tooling API query on the Lightning record pages based on their labels, you have two record pages with the same label but different API names. (This is just a guess based on the content of this module).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this answer and resolved this issue with me.

```
Check Setup > Lightning App Builder.
You need only 1 Lightning page for Opportunities. Delete all other pages.
```

ref: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l6NoQAI

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue
For some unknown reason there was two "Account Record Page", delete the clone and verify the challenge again.

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is we cannot query **FullName** field if we do have multiple fexipages on same object

Query FullName field only if the query result contains no more than one record. Otherwise, an error is returned. If more than one record exists, use multiple queries to retrieve the records.

Solution:

You can query instead NamespacePrefix + DeveloperName and use wherever you want FullName  (FullName = NamespacePrefix + DeveloperName).

I hope this will helpfull